# How to get the Window.name property from a webpage

Tags: c#, html, dom

There is a webpage that I need to get the Window.name property from.
Google Chrome console "Window.name" returns, for example, "uwt2c9xnw_64"

I have tried a few different ways but I am not finding a way to get the property.

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient();
string DownloadString = Client.DownloadString(URL);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(DownloadString);
```

Can't find anything in the HtmlDocument that would provide this property.

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse response;
response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Can't find anything in the response that would provide this property.

It has to be getting set somehow but I can't find a C# method of getting it.

Comment: What kind ad website is it? Do you have control over it?

Comment: I do not have control over it.
If it helps here is the site, https://www.ladwp.com/ladwp/faces/header/outageinformation Its easier to see if you disable javascript.

Comment: I'm confused. You are consuming this website!? And you want what? Your client is a c#-Application? As far as I know, the Window.name-Property is part of the client. If you don't have a service, that is consumed by another client, I hardly expect a Window.name-Property to be explored.

Comment: Yes I want to consume the website from a C# app. The site does a reload loop and updates a few items in the address bar, and local cookies on the first load, then the 2nd load actually loads the site, if the right things are provided. I have gotten everything except for the Window.name Property. Which gets fed back into the URL as  _afrWindowId

Comment: You can see it better if you disable JavaScript.